# Fundamental form => Gauss curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

It's straightforward to calculate the fundamental forms and the Gaussian curvature starting with a given parametrization. But how can I calculate the Gaussian curvature, given only the first fundamental form?

For example, if we have: $I= \dfrac{(du)^2+dv)^2}{[1+\frac{c}{4}(u^2+v^2)]^2}$, how should I proceed to get the Gaussian curvature?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: See wiki. It has all the equivalent formulas for $k$, including one that only involves $E, F, G$ and their derivatives in the local coordinates. Actually, here you've got $F=0$ which really simplifies everything.

Comment: Ah you mean the Brioschi formula ? I looked at this formula, but my question is: what is, for example, $E_{vv}$ ? I mean it's clear that it is the second derivation of the first entry of the fundamental form. But what explicitly is this first entry E? How can I get this from the given formula I ?

Comment: Oh. Ok, that's easy.  Treat $u$ as your first coordinate variable. In the 1st fundamental form whatever function, generically of $u$ and $v$, appears with $du^2$ is $E$, the multiple of $dudv$ is $F$ and ... Done!

Comment: Here you must get a constant curvature, something like $c$ or $c^{-1}$ because I have earlier once calculated the first fundamental form of the sphere by the stereographical projection, and the form is exactly the one you have.

Comment: Hm I tried it, but what concretely is, for example, $E_{vv}$ ? Or $E$? And you really thougt at the Brioschi formula, right?